# Ошибка в TypeScript "объекты недействительны в качестве дочерних элементов React"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, route

уважаемые разработчики. Я вот только-только начал познавать азы TypeScript в связке с React и уже столкнулся с непонятной проблемой.
Смысл моего кода: я хочу взять определённые данные с сервера в формате JSON
(с idшкой), и записать данные в UseState, потом эти данные я просто вывожу на страницу.

Вроде всё элементарно, но у меня почему-то появилась ошибка **"Ошибка: объекты недействительны в качестве дочерних элементов React (найдено: объект с ключами {улица, номер, город, почтовый индекс, гео}). Если вы хотели отобразить коллекцию дочерних элементов, используйте вместо этого массив."** Так еще и в самом редакторе вылезла ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен за помощь**

**Код страницы**

```
import React, {FC , useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { IUser } from "../types/types";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

interface ParamsUserProps{
    id: string;

}

const TemUser: FC = () => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null)

    const params = useParams<ParamsUserProps>()

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchUser()
         },[]);

    async function fetchUser(){
        try{
            const responc = await axios.get<IUser>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + params.id);
            setUser(responc.data)
        }
        catch(e){
            alert(e)
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{user?.name}</h1><h3>{user?.email}</h3><h2>{user?.address}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TemUser;
```

**Код роутера**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import UserPage from "./components/UserPage";
import ToDoPage from "./components/ToDoPage";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import TemUser from "./components/TemUser";

const App = () => {

  return(
    <Router>
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavLink to='/users'>Пользователи</NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/todo'>Список дел</NavLink>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/users" element={<UserPage/>}/>
          <Route path="/todo" element={<ToDoPage/>}/>
          <Route path="/users/:id" element={<TemUser/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе указаны две ошибки:

1. неверно указан generic параметр в `useParams`. Проблема заключается в том, что все параметры опциональны, а значит могут отсутствовать, в то время, как

   ```
   interface ParamsUserProps{
       id: string;
   }
   ```

   требует наличие свойства `id`. Таким образом решением может стать указание, что это свойство опционально:

   ```
   interface ParamsUserProps{
       id?: string;
   }
   ```
2. передача некорректного объекта в качестве дочернего элемента. Проблема заключается в том, что реакт не знает как вывести сложный объект, в данном случае `user?.address`. для решения можно выводить каждое поле отдельно, либо воспользоваться [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), чтобы получить простую строку.

   ```
   <h2>{JSON.stringify(user?.address)}</h2>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, оказывается что проблема была в самой записи `<ParamsUserProps>`, так что я её убрал

Вот мой рабочий код:

```
import React, {FC , useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { IUser } from "../types/types";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

interface ParamsUserProps{
    id: string;

}

const TemUser: FC = () => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null)

    const params = useParams() 

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchUser()
         },[]);
    async function fetchUser(){
        try{
            const responc = await axios.get<IUser>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + params.id);
            setUser(responc.data)
        }
        catch(e){
            alert(e)
        }
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>{user?.name}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TemUser;
```

В данном примере interface ParamsUserProps хоть и не объявлен в TemUser, но он задает значение string нашему param